# How do I allow http/ftp access to files I have uploaded?

Tags: urls

I am hosting on godaddy (yes, i know - shameful - but it is a proof of concept for now)

I have artifacts/installers for a mobile phone project (Windows .CAB file) and part of my build server steps FTP the files up to the server.

I can see them using the web browser FTP client on my godaddy account.

Unfortunately when I type in the url of my domain then /downloads (the location I thought I put them) i do not see the files or what I expect.  Instead I am just brought to my homepage.

I suspect there is some setting I need to do to allow a pass-through or something to allow that url to be viewed?  I think I am using the TwentyTen theme 1.2

Alternatively, how do I list all the files in a directory using some wordpress-defined page?  (like list all the files in my uploads/downloads directory that I placed there)  -

I do not want to have to manually change this - I just want them reflected on my site when they are available.

EDIT

To clarify -

I have uploaded files to my "server" and I see them at:
www.mydomainname.com/downloads using an ftp viewer.

However, when I go to that domain with a web browser it gets directed to my main homepage and is not "allowed" by WP.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress, voting to close especially considering it's godaddy so can we close it x2..

Comment: Actually, it *is* WordPress-related. The question is about providing access to uploaded files around WordPress' permalink structure.  I.e. In some cases, `http://site.url/downloads` will try to open a page rather than provide a file list.

Comment: @Wyck - I understand the anti-godaddy sentiment, however, as EAMann points out, it IS a wordpress issue.  the wordpress functionality is not letting my direct urls "go through" - it intercepts them.

Comment: Rename your .htaccess file temporarily, if that solves the issue then , well that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out a plugin like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-yo-files/).

If you don't want to go that route, I'd suggest using a page template and a technique [like this](http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/php-list-all-files-in-a-directory/) to list out the files.

Lastly, assuming you're using apache, you could set apache to allow listing directory contents (not the best idea, IMO) and then edit your .htaccess to prevent WordPress from intercepting that directory path.

Comment: Thanks - I will try the first method and if I have to resort to htaccess screwing around then I will do that.

Comment: I had already added ListYoFiles to my install byt never took the time to set it up.  Now it is working.  A great plugin!

Comment: Hah, that's pretty funny! Glad to hear that worked out for you.